# JS Mini functions

Tags: javascript, performance, function

Is it worth using mini functions in JavaScript? Example:

```
function setDisplay(id, status) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = status;
}
```

And after that, each time you want to manipulate the display attribute of any given object, you could just call this function:

```
setDisplay("object1", "block");
setDisplay("object2", "none");
```

Would there be any benefit of coding this way?

It would reduce file size and consequently page load time if that particular attribute is changed multiple times. Or would calling that function each time put extra load on processing, which would make page loading even slower?

Comment: Try this: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/javascript-performance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it worth using mini functions in JavaScript?

Yes. If done well, it will improve on:

- *Separation of concern.* For instance, a set of such functions can create an abstraction layer for what concerns *presentation* (display). Code that has just a huge series of instructions combining detailed DOM manipulation with business logic is not best practice.
- *Coding it only once.* Once you have a case where you can call such a function more than once, you have already gained. Code maintenance becomes easier when you don't have (a lot of) code repetition.
- *Readability.* By giving such functions well chosen names, you make code more self-explaining.

Concerning your example:

> ```
> function setDisplay(id, status) {
>     document.getElementById(id).style.display = status;
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> setDisplay("object1", "block");
> setDisplay("object2", "none");
> ```

This example could be improved. It is a pity that the second argument is closely tied to *implementation* aspects. When it comes to "separation of concern" it would be better to replace that argument with a boolean, as essentially you are only interested in an on/off functionality. Secondly, the function should probably be fault-tolerant. So you could do:

```
function setDisplay(id, visible) {
    let elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if (elem) elem.style.display = visible ? "block" : "none";
}

setDisplay("object1", true);
setDisplay("object2", false);
```

> Would there be any benefit of coding this way?

Absolutely.

> would [it] reduce file size...

If you have multiple calls of the same function: yes. But this is not a metric that you should be much concerned with. If we specifically speak of "one-liner" functions, then the size gain will hardly ever be noticeable on modern day infrastructures.

> ...and consequently page load time

It will have no noticeable effect on page load time.

> would calling that function each time put extra load on processing, which would make page loading even slower?

No, it wouldn't. The overhead of function calling is very small. Even if you have hundreds of such functions, you'll not see any downgraded performance.

### Other considerations

When you define such functions, it is worth to put extra effort in making those functions robust, so they can deal gracefully with unusual arguments, and you can rely on them without ever having to come back to them.

Group them into modules, where each module deals with one layer of your application: presentation, control, business logic, persistence, ...

Answer (score 5):

> It would reduce file size and consequently page load time if that particular attribute is changed multiple times. Or would calling that function each time put extra load on processing, which would make page loading even slower?

It won't make the page's loading slower. Adding a few lines here and there with vanilla js won't effect the page loading time, after all, the page's loading time is the time to load the html js and css files, so a few lines in js won't effect it. A performance issue is unlikely to happen unless you're doing something really intended that brings you into a massive calculation or huge recursion.

> Is it worth using mini functions in JavaScript?

In my opinion - Yes. You don't want to overuse that when unnecessary, after all, you don't want to write each line of code in a function right? In many cases, creating mini functions can improve the code's cleanness, readability and they can made it easier and faster to code.

With `es6` you can use a single line functions with is very nice and easy:

```
const setDisplay = (id, status) => document.getElementById(id).style.display = status;
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really affect the performance unless you execute that function 10,000 or more times.

Jquery use mini functions, like `$('#id').hide();` `$('#id').show();` and `$("#id").css("display", "none");` `$("#id").css("display", "block");`

It creates more readable code but it doesn't do that much to the performance.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

function display(div, state) {
div.style.display = state;
}

console.time("style");

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].style.display = "none";
}

console.timeEnd("style");

console.time("function");

for(var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
  display(divs[j], "block");
}

console.timeEnd("function");
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of runtime performance I’d say it doesn’t make any difference. The JavaScript engines are incredibly optimized and are able to recognize that this function is being called often and to replace it by native code, and maybe even able to inline the function call so that the cost of calling an extra function is eliminated completely.

If your intent is to reduce the JavaScript files: you save a few tens of bytes for each place in the code where the function can be used, but even if you call this mini function 100 times, you will be saving 1 or 2 kb of **uncompressed** JavaScript. If you compare the final gzipped JavaScript (which should be how you serve your resources if you care about performance) I doubt there will be any noticeable difference.

You also need to think about how this type of code will be understood by your colleagues, or whoever may have to read this code in the future. How likely it is that a new programmer in your team knows the standard DOM API? Your non-standard functions might confuse your future teammates, and require them to look into the function body to know what they do. If you have one function like this it probably doesn’t make much of a difference, but as you start adding more and more mini functions for each possible style attribute you end up with hundreds of functions that people need to get used to.

Answer (score 2):

The real benefit is ability to update on several places. Let say that you realize that you want to use classes instead of using styles. Instead of having to change on all places, you can just change that one method.

This is even more apparent when you read from a common source. Perhaps you have an API that you call with a single method.

```
let user = getData('user');
```

...but instead doing a API call, you want to use localforage to store the user data and read from the disk instead.

```
let user = getData('user');
```

... but you realized that it takes about 70-200 ms to read from localforage, so instead you store everything in memory, but reading from localforage if it's not in memory, and doing an API call if it's not in localforage. Getting user information is still the same:

```
let user = getData('user');
```

Just imagine if you wrote the whole call in every single place.

---

I usually create mini functions like these if I 1) read/write data, 2) if the code gets shorter OR more readable (i.e. the method name replaces comments), 3) or if I have repeatable code that I can sum up in a dynamic way.

Also, to quote from the book *Clean Code*: each function should do only one thing. Thinking in terms of mini functions helps with that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure of what a mini function is but if you're asking whether it's better to define functions for code that needs to be called multiple times instead of typing out/ copy-pasting those same lines of code over and over then it's better to go with option 1 for readability and file-size.

> It would reduce file size and consequently page load time if that particular attribute is changed multiple times. Or would calling that function each time put extra load on processing, which would make page loading even slower?

It's not in typical scenarios possible for the usage of such functions to put (any significant) extra load on processing that would slow down the document parsing, it's likeliness to do that would however depend on when and how you call your code to be executed but it's not like you'll be looping O(N<sup>3</sup>) and calling such functions thousands of times to impact page loading (right?) - if anything, predefined functions like that meant to take dynamic inputs would make your code neater, more uniform looking and reduce file-size...  with a very tiny obvious overhead when compared to directly accessing properties without having to go through another function. So you decide whether you want to take up that bargain depending on whether the frequency of you calling functions like that would be significant enough to be considered.

I'm sure most engines optimize repetitive code so it's (or nearly) equivalent to the same thing anyway so I'd choose readability and improve how easy it is for others to understand and follow through code instead.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is prototype language on top of that going on a leaf to say everything in JavaScript is an object so its object oriented as object oriented gets to be although at a very different level.

So the question is like we create classes in object oriented, would we develop script framework as functional programming or prototype and what will be performance hit.

so lets consider this very fine example.

```js
function abc(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;

}

person1 = new abc('jhon', 25);

person2 = new abc('mark', 46);

console.log(person1.age);console.log(person2.age);
person1.father = 'mark';
console.log(person1.father);
```

we have created a function and have used the power of this in the scope of function thus every new insurance will carry this information. and no two instances will be alike.

Then down the a line we have used prototype to add father information on instance. This where prototyping becomes awesome. Thus whole this scoping + instance + prototyping is fast.

```js
function abc(name, age) {
      name = name;
      age = age;
return name; // its either name or age no two values 
    }

    person1 = abc('jhon', 25);
        person2 = abc('mark', 46);
    console.log(person1);
    console.log(person2);
    abc.father = 'mark';
    console.log(person1.father);
       console.log(abc.father);
```

we tried the same on functional sense the whole thing fell apart. no instance + no this scoping + no new prototyping delegating down the line.  Thus in long run this approach will reduce performance as one would have to re-fetch things over and over again on top of that with t=out this scoping we are only returning single factor where as with this scooping we are packing a lot more into object. this one point.

```js
function abc(name, age) {
          this.name = name;
          this.age = age;

        }

        person1 = new abc('jhon', 25);
        person1.fatherName = 'Mark';
        person1.fatherUpdate = function (d){this.fatherAge = this.fatherName+' '+d;};
        person1.fatherUpdate(56);
        console.log(person1.fatherAge);
```

Now have added more complexity we have carried this down the line hence the scope and have added functions on top of it.
This will literally make your hair fall out if things were done in pure functional way.

Always keep in mind any given function can and may compute and execute as many things you want but it will always give single return with 99% of the time single property.

If you need more prototype way with scoping as above.

jquery way of doing things.
I had made my framework ActiveQ which uses the above its almost 30 Kb unminified and does everything jquery does and much more with template engine.

anyways lets build example - it is an example so please be kind ;

```js
function $(a){
var x; 
if(x = document.querySelector(a)) return x;
return;}


console.log($('div'));
console.log($('p'));
```

```html
<div>abc</div>
```

Now this almost 50% of your jquery selector library in just few lines.

now lets extended this

```js
function $(a){
this.x = document.querySelector(a);


}

$.prototype.changeText = function (a){
this.x.innerHTML = a;
}

$.prototype.changeColor = function (a){
this.x.style.color = a;
}

console.log(document.querySelector('div').innerText);
app = new $('div');
app.changeText('hello');
console.log(document.querySelector('div').innerText);
app.changeColor('red');
```

```html
<div>lets see</div>
```

what was the point of the whole above exercise you wont have to search through DOM over and over again as long as long one remains in scope of the function with **this**
Obviously with pure functional programming one would have to search though all over again and again.
even jquery at time forgets about what it had searched and one would have to research because this context is forwarded.

lets do some jquery style chaining full mode way - please be kind its jusrt an example.

```js
function $(a){
    return document.querySelector(a);


    }

    Element.prototype.changeText = function (a){
    this.innerHTML = a;
    return this;
    }

    Element.prototype.changeColor = function (a){
    this.style.color = a;
    return this;
    }

    console.log($('div').innerText);
   //now we have full DOm acces on simple function reurning single context
   //lets chain it
   
   console.log($('div').changeText('hello').changeColor('red').innerText);
```

```html
<div>lets see</div>
```

See the difference less line of code is way faster in performance as its working with the browser rather then pure functional way rather then creating a functional call load and search load all repeatedly

so you need to perform bunch of tasks with single output stick to functions as in conventional way and if you need to perform bunch of tasks on context as in last example where context is to manipulate properties of the element as compared to $ function which only searches and returns the element.